# I overstayed in Denmark for 3 yrs now I want to apply for schengen visa again

Tags: schengen, visa-refusals, overstaying, schengen-visas

Long story short. Last 2013 I caught overstaying in Denmark for 3 yrs I was sent back to my home country and thats 5 yrs ago now. And also now I want to apply for a Schengen visa again to visit my girlfriend in Netherlands. But I am afraid to get refusal for what happened 5 yrs ago. Is it really a big chance that i will be rejected to have a new visa? Please help.

Comment: Yes, the chance is very high that you will be refused, but you seem to know that already or you wouldn't be asking here.  Is there something more specific that we can help you with?

Comment: That's sad Yes I'm kind of aware with that. I was just hoping after some research that I have read. If you get a visa banned  for 5 years then you can apply again and might have a chance to be granted. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Aside: Most of these questions are not about travel, but about formalities. Is there another stackexchange site about travelling? There are so many questions here about Schengen and visas, they should have their own threads.

Comment: @WeatherVane You can still ask and answer questions not about visas. You can also use the site tools to filter out questions about visas. But that's something to ask about on the Meta site not here. Click on the hamburger thing on the  top right and select Travel Meta.

Comment: `visit my girlfriend in Netherlands` Why cannot she visit you considering your situation ?

Answer (score 4):

You would have to convince the Dutch officials that **this** time, you won't overstay. Can you make a credible explanation why that won't happen? Saying *"I wouldn't do that, honestly"* won't be enough with your history.

- It might help if you had a *stable* and *well-paid job* that requires you to return. Something no sane person would give up, even for a girlfriend. Earning [more than you could in the EU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_European_countries_by_average_wage#European_countries_by_monthly_average_wage) ...
- It might help if you were very young in 2013 and more mature now, but you are not much older now.
- If you have lived together with your girlfriend for a long time, you might have a chance for a dependent visa. Ask on Expatriates Stack Exchange. (But personally I doubt that will work.)